Volume-preserving charts for submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$
The 2 dimensional sphere can be covered by area-preserving charts via cylindrical projection. Is it possible to cover any submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with volume-preserving charts?

Google "Moser's trick."
